# Detectron2 Tutorial - torch version 1.11 not combatable with Detectron2 v0.6

Tags: python, torch, coda

When trying to run Detectron2 Tutorial I had an error because  torch 1.11 is not compatible with Detectron2 v0.6

solution:
add: !pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
and then change:
!pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
to:
!pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu111/torch1.10/index.html

Answer (score 2):

solution: add:
!pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
and then change:
!pip install torch==1.10.0+cu111 torchvision==0.11.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu111/torch_stable.html
to:
!pip install detectron2 -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu111/torch1.10/index.html